# delete unused outlets in xcode

Tags: xcode, outlet

In Xcode I created an outlet and made it connected. Then I deleted the connection by clicking the cross in connection inspector. However, the unused outlet always appears there. How can I deleted the unused outlet. (I have deleted the code in the .m file)

Comment: Similar question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328026/how-to-remove-all-references-for-outlet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very easy, just click the delete button

```
Connections Inspector panel
```

[image: click the X]