# Xcode Interface Builder - "correct" way to delete/rename miswired IBOutlets / IBActions?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

I am new to Xcode, working through Swift, so I'm not sure if what I am decribing is actually a bug.

When using interface builder and the assistant editor, I can create lables, buttons etc, and create Outlets and Action in the code with a control-drag.

So long as I am perfect, no problem.   But I seem to run into problems if, for example, I make a mispelling of the object name.  Or, I choose outlet instead of action.   I can't seem to find a way to make a correction that does't seem to totally screw up the IDE.   Even if I delete the object in the  IB  and the code, it seems to leave  problems behind when I build.   Or, if I try to delete the line in code and re-drag it, a new line of code is created, but the object seems to now reference the new name, and the old, now missing name.

Again, I am working with Swift --- Since I don't use/know Objective-C I don't know if there is a similar behavior using that language.

Appreciate any pointers.   (Other than don't use the Interface builder / storyboards / Swift.)

Comment: TO clarify -- what is the best way to correct a simple misspelling? (Or I just plain picked a bad name, and now desire to fix that -- so the name is not just in the connection, but throughout the code. (i.e., FInd/Replace that includes the IB itself?)

Comment: To rename a IBOutlet without deleting the connection try this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37313505/7250862

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the Connections inspector to break the connection.  Then you can modify/delete the object and/or the code without having to worry.

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- I updated my own question to clarify:   -- what is the best way to correct a simple misspelling (or better yet,  to correct to make a variable name more meaningful , that appears multiple time in the code.

Comment: @user1639473 -- There's no find/replace that includes the IB itself (AFAIK, they may add that feature at some point). So the procedure is 1) break the connection 2) find/replace in the code 3) recreate the connection. Step 3 can be done by control-dragging from the IB object to the existing line of code, or you can drag (w/o control) from the empty circle in the *left margin of the code editor*, to the *object in IB*.

Comment: To rename an object use Edit > Refactor > Rename (or right click on an object). This also renames any IBOutlet reference in Interface Builder.

Comment: Craig, you can't use Refactor/Rename when working with Swift. Xcode throws you an error when you try that.

Comment: Hi, perhaps is it a little out of subject: I face the same problem (renaming an IBOutlet) in Objective-C. The IBOutlet was created by ctrl-drag'n dropping a button from a storyboard to a .h file. When renaming the IBOutlet in the .h file, the app crashes at the execution in the simulator because of the old IBOutlet name. To fix it, I opened the file .storyboard in a text editor, looked for the XML tag `<connections>`, and removed the outdated connection.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer is fine, but there are a few ways to do the same thing.

## Method One

Right click the view in the storyboard and then click the little x by the referencing outlet.

[image]

## Method Two

Right click the view name in the Document Outline. Then click the little x by the referencing outlet.

[image]

## Method Three

Select the view on the storyboard and then click the Connections Inspector. Then you can click the little x to remove an outlet reference.

[image]

## Extra References in Code

[image]

If you are getting outlet connections in code that you didn't add yourself see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324993/3681880).

Answer (score 7):

You can find unused IBOutlets in the file in which they're declared by looking in the "gutter" of the source editor for an "unfilled hole".

[image]