# Set UIButton Image in Swift - currently unwraps as nil

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, optional-values

I am having a difficult time setting an image of a UIButton. I have checked other posts on how to do this, and it seems straightforward enough (but then, here I am).

In my program, the image that the button displays depends on trip.weather. I am using a switch to set the image before trying to set the button's image. However, while debugging, the console displays the following:

'2015-05-03 13:40:31.117 PackPlanner[581:4465]  < UIImage: 0x7fd2a843fac0>, {600, 300}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)'

```
class TripOverviewViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet var highTempLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lowTempLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var weatherLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numOfPeopleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var sunriseLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var sunsetLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherButtonImage: UIButton!

@IBAction func weatherButton(sender: UIButton) {
}


var tripItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the trip detail.
            if let trip: Trip = self.tripItem as? Trip{

                if var label = self.locationLabel {
                    label.text = trip.location
                }
                if var label = self.numOfPeopleLabel {
                    label.text = trip.numOfPeople.stringValue
                }
                if var label = self.dateLabel {
                    var formattedDate = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(trip.startDate, dateStyle: .LongStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)
                    label.text = formattedDate
                }
                if var label = self.weatherLabel {
                    label.text = trip.weather
                }

                var theImage = UIImage(named: "Sunny") as UIImage!
                switch trip.weather {
                    case "Partly Cloudy":
                        theImage = UIImage(named:"PartlyCloudy")
                    case "Light Snow":
                        theImage = UIImage(named:"LightSnow")
                    case "Rainy":
                        theImage = UIImage(named:"Rainy")
                    default:
                        theImage = UIImage(named:"Sunny")

                }
                NSLog(" \(theImage.description)") //for debugging
                self.weatherButtonImage.setImage(theImage, forState: .Normal)

    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.configureView()


}
```

Comment: Which line does it stop on?  Which object is nil?

Comment: Here: self.weatherButtonImage.setImage(theImage, forState: .Normal). The UIImage itself seems to be fine. I just edited the question to show the output of the NSLog that is right before the error.

Comment: So either  `theImage` is nil or `weatherButtonImage` is nil.  Which is it?  Have you double checked your image names?

Comment: weatherButtonImage is nil. I have checked the image names so many times, it makes me crazy! :(

Comment: Ok, so why is `weatherButtonImage` nil? - Did you connect the IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yep. Used the drag n' drop method from storyboard to file.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and check if `weatherButtonImage` is nil there.  Try removing the IBOutlet connection and re-creating it.  The error message you are receiving is clear and you can see that your button is nil - you just need to work out why.

Comment: You need to implicitly unwrap adding an exclamation "!" At the end UIImage(named: "yourImage")!

Comment: Cast as UIImage! Makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after NSLog(" (theImage.description)")

```
    if let tempButton = self.weatherButtonImage
    {
    tempButton.setImage(theImage, forState:.Normal)
    } else
    { NSLog("Button is nil")
    }
```

To determine if its your button that is nil.

If your button is nil, reconnect it in storyboard.

Comment: Checkout this link for info on how to reconnect your IBOutlet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523086/xcode-interface-builder-correct-way-to-delete-rename-miswired-iboutlets-ib

Comment: Thank you. I just tried something like this, and the Button is definitely nil. I suspect I must have done something weird while in the storyboard file.

I reconnected it. No luck.

Comment: You could have a bad link in there from a previous attempt.  Go to your storyboard, at the top of your view controller, right click on the yellow circle with a square in it.  If you see any connections with a yellow triangle, remove them, as they are bad links.  I have to do this all the time.

Comment: I see you run configureView when tripItem is set.  Is it possible to set a tripItem before the view is loaded?  If so, that's bad news for your button.

Comment: I think you are onto something with your last comment. I moved the code for setting the button's image from configureView() to viewDidLoad(). Works! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I am being greedy for info now, but can you explain why my original method was problematic?

Comment: ConfigureView should only determine the image and not place it on the button since configureView could be run before the view loads and the button is created...

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually, yes. Seems simple enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure theImage exists and is not nil? UIImage may not be able to find that image named "Sunny". Another possibility is that self.weatherButtonImage is nil at that point (I see it's an outlet), so try setting it when the IB layout is complete at viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: This probably should've been a comment.