# Why did I get a fatal error in Swift? unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm gettiing a fatal error and i don't know why. i have tried changing the '!' with '?' at _title but it still don't work.

```
class Post: NSObject, NSCoding {
   
    private var _img: String!
    private var _title: String!
    private var _descLbl: String!
    
    var img: String {
        return _img
    }
    
    var titleLbl: String {
        return _title
    }
    
    var descLbl: String {
        return _descLbl
    }
    
    init(imagePath: String, title: String, description: String) {
        self._img = imagePath
        self._title = title
        self._descLbl = description
    }
}
```

Here is where i get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descLbl: UILabel!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    func configureCell(post: Post) {
        title.text = post.titleLbl //Here i get the error
        descLbl.text = post.descLbl
    }
}
```

Here i call the function configureCell in ViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell") as? PostCell {
        cell.configureCell(post)
        return cell
    }else{
        var cell = PostCell()
        cell.configureCell(post)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Post` class does not compile: `error: type 'Post' does not conform to protocol 'NSCoding'`

Comment: What's the purpose of those backing private variables in the `Post` class? If you want read-only properties just declare them as constants (`let`)

Comment: Is the class of the custom cell set to `PostCell` in Interface Builder?

Comment: Duplicate of [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most possibly that your `@IBOutlet`:s are missing proper connections. You reach the runtime exception, however, only when you try to access these "free-floating" disconnected outlet properties for the first time; namely in the `.configureCell(...)` call in `tableView(..)`.

E.g., the following scaled-down example yields the same error for "non-connected" `@IBOutlet`:s

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

        // non-connected outlets
        @IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var descLbl: UILabel!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        func configureCell() {
            title.text = "foo" // <--
            descLbl.text = "bar"
        }
}

// ... elsewhere
var cell = PostCell()    
cell.configureCell() 
    // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Make sure that, e.g. in the *Connections Inspector* in the Interface Builder, that all these three outlets are properly connected to the intended UI elements. For details, see e.g. the following thread

- [Xcode Interface Builder - "correct" way to delete/rename miswired IBoutlets / IBactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523086/xcode-interface-builder-correct-way-to-delete-rename-miswired-iboutlets-ib)

Comment: Thanks for your answer dfri. Everything is connected the right way, so what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidDume Have you double checked vadian:s note above; that your custom cells are set to `PostCell` in the attributes inspector in the Interface Builder?

Comment: I fixed it. I didn't put the identifier at the cell in the storyBoard so this is why this code "tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell")" didn't work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Dume I see, a common mistake, good to hear you worked it out :)