# How does one remove a IBAction link to main.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this weird Problem where I have 4 `UIButton`s in my App not working at all, even though i have double checked on having them correctly linked to the Storyboard. So i tried to disconnect and reconnect them but the icon indicating that its linked didn´t disappear. So I checked what else the function is linked to and it seems somehow it got linked to the main.storyboard, and i guess for that reason, these are the only ones not working.[image: This is how it looks like]

So I tried to disconnect it from Main.storyboard, but to no success so far.
How can I remove a connection to the storyboard as sender and why does it appear in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried to remove it from connection inspector?

Comment: I have tried to disconnect it from the link- Button within the Code and have disconnected it via Inspector from the Buttons, but the main.storyboard doesn´t seem to have one. Or atleast i can´t locate where to find the connections of main.storyboard

Comment: Go to the storyboard, and select the view controller-- you can see all the connections there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too did it accidentally for a button.

Connected a correct segue to the button and accidentally connected one more to a `UICollectionView` and I was getting this :

[image]

Checked the `storyboard` on right clicking the button :

[image]

and found the two outlet connected. Removed it on clicking the cross icon and it worked.

If you click on the connection showing in `UIViecontroller` it will not redirect here.

you can also check all the connected referencing outlets here:

[image]

Comment: That exactly what i was looking for, just the other way around, it´s weirdly the function that connected to the Storyboard instead of the Button, and i can´t find this exact window for the storyboard. If you know where to locate that window fitting for a storyboards links i´d be grateful

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you are asking for. I have updated the answer for more reference to check referencing outlets on a button.

Answer (score 1):

So i fixed the Problem by copying the code to another file and only "rewriting" the functions that were linked to the given problem.
All i could find to this problem was some old answer that explained that the link referrs to a ViewController that the Code originates from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324993/10160115
Even though the Code i wrote is not copied it seems that XCode has created exactly such a referral to the storyboard it was linked to, so it linked the function to itself but couldn´t find any Button to link it to so it just linked it to nothingness.
It fixed the problem and the buttons work the way they´re supposed to be now but it´s a weird way of fixing this, but since there seems to be no connections inspector for the storyboard itself i wouldn´t know how else to fix this

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should (for macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Xcode Version 11.1):

1. Close your project and close Xcode
2. Open `/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete your cache of project
3. Open `/Users/ХХХХХ /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex` and delete all cache from this directory
4. Open your project again and click `Product > Build`